# XCode Image from Server

Tags: php, xcode, json, image

I have a php page that randomly selects an image source an example output would be:

http://mywebsite.com/lion.jpg

How would i get Xcode to get the output and use it as an image source. (I am using the MainStoryboard)

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the image manually.  `UIImage's` `imageWithData:` will load an image from the website.

In your view controller add an IBOutlet for the ImageView.

```
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView* backgroundImageView;
```

In your Storyboard add a `UIImageView` behind everything and assign it to the backgroundImageView outlet.

In your `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller add:

```
NSString *ImageURL = @"YourURLHere";
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:ImageURL]];
self.backgroundImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: I am very new to Xcode. Could you tell me how i could get the image url and set it as the background of my app